# How to ignore child DIV if parent div has some specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I ignore the class `extra` for child div with class `child2`?

```
<div class="parent extra">
    <div class="child1">
        Some text
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

The `extra` class is used for translating the texts inside `divs`,but I don't want to translate the `child div` with class `child2`. How can I filter this?

Comment: This would entirely depend on the context you're using to select the elements, and what you're trying to do with them. We need more information to help you.

Comment: The 'extra' class is used for translating the texts inside divs,but I don't want to translate the child div with class 'child2'.How can I filter this?

Comment: If none of the asnwers worked or you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The 'extra' class is used for translating the texts inside divs,but I don't want to translate the child div with class 'child2'.How can I filter this?

```
$('.extra :not(.child2)')
```

This selector is saying

1. Grab all elements with class `extra`
2. Search all direct/nested children(the meaning of the space)
3. Grab all direct/nested children which do not have a class of `child2`

Comment: The snippet I posted here is not original as actual one has vast amount html markups.So,I wanted to solve it by myself like everyone suggested a solution.If not solved,will post actual html here. –

Answer (score 0):

You can :

1. loop all div with parent class  -->`$( ".parent" ).each()`
2. check if the current class has a class extra --> `if($(this).hasClass( "extra" ){}`
3. if the current parent class has a class extra loop all children and check  if it has a child with class : child2 `$(this).children().each()` and `if($(this).hasClass( "child2" )){}`
4. If it is the case get the parent and do some process...

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bp0bjg46/3/)

#### EDIT:

[same logic in one line code](http://jsfiddle.net/pzq9hrg2/1/)